# Flutter | remove extra space from Switch widget

Tags: flutter, material-design

I'm working on the below screen in a flutter app, but when I use Switch widget it breaks the alignment, because there is hardcoded height and width already defined in flutter.

[image]
[image]

How can I get rid of the extra space

Note: same issue also using Radio button or Checkbox

Comment: paste code to understand issue better. Please tell your required screen in a image.

Comment: Of course you can do it by changing theme but It against Material Design guideline(current size is finger touch size). https://material.io/design/guidelines-overview/#addition

Comment: @RahulKhatri it's a common issue whenever Switch widget used.

Comment: How did you display the borderlines of those widgets in you second image?

Comment: @user3739779 when you run the project using vscode it's open a browser tab where you can inspect the widgets and check their borders

Answer (score 10):

```
SizedBox(
  width: 50,
  height: 20,
  child: Switch(
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
  value: value,
  onChanged: (bool newvalue) {
    onChangeMethod(newvalue);
  },
  activeTrackColor: Colors.grey,
  activeColor: Colors.black,
  ),
);
```

You can refer https://flutterwebbies.com/flutter/how-to-remove-extra-space-from-switch-widget/

Comment: This one was the most complete answer, the combination of SizedBox() and MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap allowed me to resize the Switch widget

Answer (score 6):

[image]

You could try to wrap your Switch widget in Container

```
Container(
  height: 20,
  width: 50,
  child: Switch(
   value: _value,
   onChanged: (value){
    setState((){
      _value = value
    });
   }
  )
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately still the same issue

Comment: @Yogesh Chawla worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

To remove the padding from the `Switch` widget you need to set the `materialTapTargetSize` to `shrinkWrap`.

```dart
Switch(
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
  onChanged: (bool value) {},
)
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than hard coding a random height

Comment: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap "Shrinks the tap target size to the minimum provided by the Material specification." It does NOT remove all the padding.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the `Switch` with `SizedBox` and set your width and height.

Answer (score 1):

We Can use Container With Transform.scale widget and set max Constraints according to requirements

```
Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 6.0),
                child: Transform.scale(
                       scale: 0.6,
                       child: Switch(
                                materialTapTargetSize:MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                                activeColor: Colors.red,
                                onChanged: (bool value) { },
                                     ) 
                                      ),
               ),
```

[image: switch look like]

Answer (score 0):

We can use Container with constraints to set maxHeight

```
      Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 5.0),
                child: Switch(
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  value: true,
                  activeColor: kAccentColor,
                  onChanged: (p0) => p0,
                ),
              ),
```